# JasperReports class path

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to include the *.jrxml* file in my *NetBeans* swing project. I use *NetBeans 7.0.1*. I created a package inside source package called "rep" and created a simple *.jrxml* file called "rp.jrxml".
I have installed the *iReport* plugin in *NetBeans*. When I set a outer *.jrxml* file, it is showed ("D:/MyReports/firstreport.jrxml") but when I set the *NetBeans* package path, it was not shown. Here is my code.

```
try {
       String reportSource="/rep/rp.jrxml";  //and also "rep/rp.jrxml" is used.no result.            
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then the following error is given;

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rep\rp.jrxml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

How I can keep *jrxml* files inside my *NetBeans* project and use *jrxml* files inside the project?

Comment: Use YourClass.getResource method which should return the URL for the rp.jrxml specific to yourClass package. Use the returned URL to determine the actual path.

Comment: Thanks.but It didn't work.Then it gives another error `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No report compiler set for language : null`

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
public class TestJasper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String reportSource = "resources/report1.jrxml";
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My project structure:

```
build
    classes
        TestJasper.class
dist 
nbproject
resources
    report1.jrxml 
src
    TestJasper.java
```

***UPDATED:***
For solving `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No report compiler set for language : null` problem you can try to set `groovy` report language and add `groovy-all-jdk14` library to classpath.
 
You can get groovy library [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all-jdk14/1.6.9/).

The sample of report header with language set to `groovy`:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
... 
language="groovy" 
...>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Alex. The class paths are same as I have created.Only difference is projects and class names. but it didn't work. The error comes as mentioned above  `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No report compiler set for language : null`

Comment: In your sample you wrote: `String reportSource="/rep/rp.jrxml";`  Please try to change it to this expression: `String reportSource="rep/rp.jrxml";`

Comment: @Mr.Alex, thanks for your commments. I changed it in every format.but didnt work.

Comment: I think that you are using the different version of JasperReports (in iReport and in your project libraries)

Comment: Can you post the report's header?

Comment: thanks for the link .but I have added Jasper report 4.1 libraries.(about jasperforge.org... )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4413/discussion-between-alex-k-and-aash-maharoon)

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution.It is better to provide an absolute path in the jar file itself.Also when the jar is run,using *.jasper file is better to use instead of .jrxml it may cause for the speed of generating the report as well.Then  that .jasper can be sent to JasperFillManager as a inputstream. That is it.