# Getting "JRException: No report compiler set for language" error. How to resolve?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jasper-reports

Below are part of my code. When I use Mysql as my database all working fine including JasperReports, but once I change the connection to Oracle database (12 c) and I get this error when passing parameter to the JasperReports's report.

```
<% 
String datef =request.getParameter("datef");
String datet =request.getParameter("datet");


try {
String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:test"; 
Connection conn = null; 
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"system","1234");

String jrxmlFile ="C:/report/report1.jrxml";
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("datef",datef);
map.put("datet",datet);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,map,conn);
byte bytes[] = new byte[10000]; 
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
ByteArrayOutputStream PDFStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, PDFStream); 
exporter.exportReport(); 
bytes = PDFStream.toByteArray(); 
response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);    
PDFStream.close();  

OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 
outputStream.flush(); 
outputStream.close(); 
}catch(Exception ex){
   out.println("Error"+ex);
} 
%>
```

My error message:

```
Error foundnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No report compiler set for language : null
```

Note I got two set of *JasperReports*'s report:

1) Connect using MySql as database

2) Connect using Oracle as database

both are able to preview in Studion (iReport) by manually enter the parameter)

This is my report query:

```
SELECT
 CI_ID,
 Status,
 CI_name,
 Serial_num,
 Manufacturer,
 model,
 warranty_end,
 refresh_date,
 core_id,
 departm
FROM
 laptop
WHERE
 refresh_date >= $P{datef}
 and refresh_date <= $P{datet}
ORDER BY
 refresh_date ASC
```

I import all the related .jar in the lib folder, for oracle I add (ojdbc7), and the Connect port are 1522 and the SID name is "test" which can connect using Oracle SQL Developer, password and username are correct. am I missing anything here please do let me know thanks.

*UPDATE:*

I set the Language and now I get this error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : report2
```

Comment: Did you set the language in report (Java or Groovy)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jasper report "No report compiler set for language : null" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380439/jasper-report-no-report-compiler-set-for-language-null-error) & [Java, iRpeort and JasperSoft - No report set for compiler: null](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14433923/876298) & [JasperReports class path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7823756/876298)

Comment: @Alex K Thanks for fast response , and I just do the changes in the Language and now I get this error (Error 404 Page not foundnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : report2)

Comment: 1) I think it is not a brilliant idea to ask another question in the same post. 2) You did not post the *jrxml* file 3) You did not post the full stacktrace 4) Please, don't rollback changes of your post without any comments - I tried to help you

Comment: I use Jasper Report 3.0 version and problem solved